# Excel - Filter rows based on starting string, read number from filtered rows and perform arithmetic operation to generate column summary

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am having a Project and resource allocation report. I need help in generating the formula to display summary in the bottom section of my report.

Here're the specifications of my report:

- `Column A` from `Row 2` to `Row 15` represents the Resource (persons) allocated for each project
- `Column B`, `Column C`.... represents the percentage of resource allocated in each project per month
- Each resource of `column A` is merged into 2 cells because each resource can either work in 1 or 2 project per month
- Resource working on single project in a month will have both the cells merged . Resource working on 2 projects will have 2 rows representing the project
- Against each project there is number representing the percentage of that resource allocated to the project

Here's the screenshot of my report:

[image: Project and resource allocation report screenshot]

At the bottom report I am having summary section which represents the count of resources allocated per project. Currently these counts are manually added by me. I need help in generating the formula for these summary. Here's what I am trying to achieve:

1. Read  string from cells (A20 - A24)
2. Do a lookup in the month column (B2 - B15) to get the cells starting with project string
3. Filter the numbers from the above cells (from step 2)
4. Do summation of the numbers and divide by `100` to get the resource count

So far I am able to generate this formula which reads the number from the row passed to it:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR((MID(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2))),1)*1),""))
```

which gives me number `50` from cell `B2` containing `"Project A 50%"` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have O365, you can use the `FILTER` function:

- Filter the list by the contents of A20:Ann
- Return just the last space separated value in each string (the percentage)
- Sum the results
- Use `IFERROR` in case the project doesn't exist

  ```
    =IFERROR(SUM(--((TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B$2:B$15,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A20,B$2:B$15)))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))))),"")
  ```

or *(depending on whether you want to return zero or `""` for a non-existent entry)*

```
    =IFERROR(SUM(--((TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B$2:B$15,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A20,B$2:B$15)))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))))),"")
```

***Edit:** in the comments, the OP mentions that Projects can be similarly named but be prepended by a character, and these should be treated separately. This requires a different Filter criteria:*

```
=IFERROR(SUM(--((TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B$2:B$15,LEFT(B$2:B$15,LEN($A20))=$A20)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: It is also counting for starting where project is present as substring. For example. "AProject A" is getting treated as positive of "Project A". Is there a easy way to restrict it just for "Project A" at start (to do text match just for start string)?

Comment: @Anonymous To restrict the comparison to just the starting portion of the Project, one merely has to change the Filter criteria.  eg. `LEFT(B$2:B$15,LEN($A20))=$A20`.  I'll post an edit.

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't like this answer much, but please [keep an open mind](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Presumably this will not be the last time you need to analyse this table. If you restructure now, your life will be easier later.

1. Merged cells feel like a good idea at the time but they will only cause you grief later
2. Combining variables into a single cell "Project A 50%" is always going to make analysis more difficult since you now have to separate those variables to make sense of them
3. Entering data cross-tabulated might be slightly simpler, but it comes at a cost. What if you now need to produce a report asking you the Year-on-Year quarterly resource assigned to Project A? Also, what happens when you get to the next year? Create a new table? Then how do you compare them?

I'm not trying to be obtuse here, but after 25 years working with data in Excel and other systems, I want to encourage people to think about what they might need to do later.

Something like this will serve you best:

[image]

Note that this is formatted as a Table using Ctrl+T or "Format as Table" on the Home tab of the ribbon.

This structure has a number of benefits:

1. Entering data is now trivially easy by just typing on a new row
2. Analysis can be done across any dimension (person, month, project) with a pivot table - no complex formulas for what should be simple questions
3. Charting is now trivially easy
4. You can add new information to each row as columns. Perhaps you want to add the person's line manager or team name to the row as an XLOOKUP from another table, or perhaps you want to add notes on performance or vacation during that month for that person
5. If you ever need to copy this into another spreadsheet or send it to someone as a csv or have it loaded into a table in a database or a dataframe for analysis, you won't have to spend time un-merging and filling the empty cells before you can do that

EDIT:

To answer your question with this revised data structure, you could simply create a pivot table:

[image]

Comment: FlexYourData you do not provide an answer to the question. Instead you give some general advice on spreadsheet organisation.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate downvote, but I have edited to provide the answer.

Comment: I removed the downvote. I never used Pivot tables - you might explain to set that pivot table up given his problems with a rather simple issue.

Comment: Thanks @FlexYourData . I appreciate you points, and details your shared. But pivot table representation isn't an option for me. But I note your points, and completely agree with what you explained above. You still have my +1

Answer (score 2):

Your data representation in rows 2-15 is a mess because you combine two pieces of information in one cell. That will basically disable the usability of all numeric cell functions. Split the project identifier and the resource amount up in two columns.

Given project identifier in Column B  and resource in Column C
you would simply set cell B20 to "=sumif(b$2:b$15;"A";c$2:c$15)".
You would modify that formula to "B" for Project B.

For faster entry without modifying the formula create a hidden column containing A B C D .... and let the fixed string from the formula above point to the hidden values A B C D ....

Comment: thanks @r2d3 . I understand what you are saying, and the complexities it has. But unfortunately this format is part of the desired format requested for the report. Also "Project A", "Project B" are just the placeholders. Sorry, I should have mentioned it in the question. But you have my +1

Comment: Thank you. But given those stupid requirements I have another solution for you.You enter the data like I described and you output your reporting on a different sheet or another area of this sheet. Combing information into a cell is simple with like =A4&" "A5 for instance. :) This way you might comply with your reporting requirements.