# Filter columns based on starting string, read number from filtered cells and perform arithmetic operation to generate summary of two rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am having a Project and resource allocation report. I need help in generating the formula to display summary on the right section of the report.

Here're the specifications of my report:

- Column A from Row 2 to Row 15 represents the Resource (persons) allocated for each project
- Column B, Column C.... represents the percentage of resource allocated in each project per month
- Each resource of column A is merged into 2 cells because each resource can either work in 1 or 2 project per month
- Resource working on single project in a month will have both the cells merged . Resource working on 2 projects will have 2 rows representing the project
- Against each project there is number representing the percentage of that resource allocated to the project

Here's the screenshot of my report:

[image: Project Resource Allocation Sheet screenshot]

Here, in the summary, I am representing the total number of weeks each person will be spending on each project. To keep the calculation simplified, I am assuming each month is equivalent to exactly 4 weeks. So,

- If a Person A is working 100% in Project B in February. Then number to be considered for summation in summary should be 4 for Project B
- Similarly if Person A is working 50-50% on 2 projects in January. Then number to be considered for summation should be 2-2 weeks for each project

In general, the number to be considered in summary could be mathematically represented as:

```
4 *[Percentage from column] / 100
```

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

1. Read string from cells (F1 - J1)
2. Do a lookup in the person column on two rows (B2, C2... ) and (B3, C3...) to get the cells starting with project string
3. Filter the numbers from the above cells (from step 2)
   Do summation of the numbers and divide by 100 and multiply by 4 (to get number of weeks)

Here's what I created taking answer for similar question as reference from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1620103/1265437):

```
=IFERROR((IFERROR(SUM(--((TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER($B2:$C2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J$1,$B2:$C2)))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))))), 0) + IFERROR(SUM(--((TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER($B3:$C3,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J$1,$B3:$C3)))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))))), 0))*4, "")
```

which gives me 6 for Project B. Is there a way to simplify this? I think I am doing a lot of redundant operations here. Also, it returns 0 if project not found. I prefer empty string in it's place

Feel free to suggest if there's a better way to perform this calculation.

**Note:**

1. For column with two cells merged, calculation should be considered just once for that person.
2. Calculation of my summary is based on data from two rows
3. Here I am using Person names ("Person A", "Person B", etc) and Project names ("Project A", "Project B", etc) strings just as a placeholder text. In real report these are going to real values with random alphabets.

---

PS: It is similar to my previous question where I was generating summary on single column, where two cells within the column could be merged: [*Excel - Filter rows based on starting string, read number from filtered rows and perform arithmetic operation to generate column summary*](https://superuser.com/q/1620098/1265437) . However, here I am performing calculation on two rows to get the summary. And merged row cells needs to be considered only once for calculation.

Comment: You’re getting some detailed expert help here already, but just my observation for a different approach. Unmerge column A so that each person’s name appears on the row(s) for the project(s) they work on. You’re trying to make a pretty sheet, but (to me) it’s more important to make a practical one. Treat the data more like a simple DB, where you can have multiple records per person. You should then be able to do pivot tables to get the report you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, try this shorter formula proposal.

1] In `F2`, formula copied across and down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(4*TEXT(SUBSTITUTE($B2:$C3,F$1,""),"0%;;;\0"))
```

2] Your previous question can also be solved by this same formula, I put it in A19:C23.

In `B19`, formula copied across and down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(B$2:B$15,$A19,""),"0%;;;\0"))
```

And,

**Edit**

**To remove 0**

1] Using cell format :

All formula cells format in  >> "Accounting" >> "Symbol", choose "None" >> "Decimal place" : click "1"

2] Using IFERROR(1(/1.......),"") adding to F2 formula, and become >>

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMPRODUCT(4*TEXT(SUBSTITUTE($B2:$C3,F$1,""),"0%;;;\0"))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bosco_yip. It works well. But it gives me 0 as you already pointed out. Can't thins be handled through the formula to replace 0s with empty string?

Comment: Using IFERROR(1(/1.......),""), please see my post new edited.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is more complicated because the range to process is multi-dimensional. (In your previous question it was only a single dimension).

One way to process is to turn it into a single dimensional array which can be done using `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML`.  There is a limitation in that the string resulting from the `TEXTJOIN` function can not exceed `32,767` characters.  If that will be a problem, then a VBA or Power Query solution might be better.

Also, `FILTERXML` is not available on Mac versions or on Excel Online.

If those limitations do not apply, then

```
F2: =IFERROR(4*SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$B2:$C3) & "</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'" & F$1 & "')]")," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[last()]")),"")
```

- Fill right and down
- We first create an `XML` (using `TEXTJOIN`) to create a separate node for each cell

  - our `xPath` argument returns only those nodes that `start-with` the Project name in row 1.
  - We then use `SUBSTITUTE` to create another `XML` based on space-separated nodes with an `xPath` that returns the last node.
  - Do the mathematical operations.

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you do **NOT** have the `FILTERXML` function, try this formula *(O365 Mac or Windows and Excel Online)* which uses a different method to convert the 2D array into a 1D array for processing:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(4*TRIM(RIGHT(
   SUBSTITUTE(LET(
        seq,IF(SEQUENCE(99)=1,1,(SEQUENCE(99)-1)*99),
        x,TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",99),TRUE,$B2:$C3),seq,99)),
        y, FILTER(x,LEFT(x,LEN(F$1))=F$1),y),
   " ",REPT(" ",99)),99))),"")
```

This formula still has the 32,767 character limit. Whether you run into that will depend mostly on how many spaces there are in the project name.  Formula to compute is roughly:

- a = average number of characters in the cell
- b = number of spaces in the cell
- c = number of cells

  ```
   (a+b*99) * c
  ```

If you had, for example, `15` characters, `5` spaces, and `24` cells, that would work out to about `12,000` characters.

Comment: Thanks @Ron. Unfortunately both of these are restriction for me *Mac versions* and  *Excel Online*. I recreated this using the one you shared yesterday and it seems to work fine `=IFERROR((IFERROR(SUM(--((TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER($B2:$C2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J$1,$B2:$C2)))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))))), 0) + IFERROR(SUM(--((TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER($B3:$C3,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J$1,$B3:$C3)))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))))), 0))*4, "")` . Could this be simplified? And if project doesn't exist, how could i modify it to return empty string instead of returning `0` ?

Comment: By the way *32,767 characters* limit of `FILTERXML` is fine wit me. My report will be for only 12 columns (i.e month in year)  * 2 (rows) = 24 cells

Comment: @Anonymous See my edit for a formula that should work.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfelf. It works great. For some of the column I am not getting values, most likely it is because of `12,000` char restriction which you already mentioned. But it is ok if there isn't a easy way to handle it, I can work around it to keep chars in range

Comment: @Anonymous I doubt that's the reason. And the limit is `32,767`; not `12,000`. Possibly not an exact match someplace.  What's the error if you remove the `IFERROR` clause?  What does the data look like (number of characters and spaces) that's being processed?